# QTreeView: How to put multiple widgets in one cell?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I'd like to put multiple widgets in one cell of a QTreeView. QTreeView already does this with check boxes (e.g if you set ItemIsUserCheckable and ItemIsEditable). For example, how would I show a small tool button next to a line edit, instead of the check box next to the line edit?

I've gone through the whole deal of subclassing Qtreeview, implementing a custom ItemDelegate, and overriding paint( ) and createEditor( ). And that works if I only need to render simple things, like a single line edit, single button, etc. However, I cannot get it to work for nested components.

I tried to create a QHBoxLayout, add a QLineEdit and a QToolBarButton to it, add the layout to a new QWidget, and return the whole thing from createEditor( ). However, nothing shows up.

Can anybody provide a simple example?

Thanks!

Comment: Just create your own widget (by creating new class) and set look just as you want

Comment: You can always use `QStyle` to paint the widgets manually. This wouldn't be hard since you are overriding `paint` anyway.